# por qué el id de retorno es erroneo en spring jpa

Tags: java, oracle, spring, jpa

Tengo la siguiente entidad:

```
package cl.mesos.cancelacion.models.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
@Table(name="CLC_SOLICITUD_CANCELACION")
public class SolicitudCancelacion implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="CLCSC_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_Sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "id_Sequence", sequenceName = "CLC_SOLICITUD_CANCELACION_seq")
    private Integer clcscId;

    @Column(name="CLCM_CD_MOTIVO")
    private Integer clcscCdMotivo;

    @Column(name="CLCSC_PROPUESTA")
    private String clcscPropuesta;

    @Column(name="CLCSC_CD_CONVENIO")
    private Integer clcscCdConvenio;

    @Column(name="CLCSC_FECRE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date clcscFeCre;

    @Column(name="CLCSC_FE_HASTA")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date clcscFeHasta;

    @Column(name="CLSCSC_FECHA_SOLICITUD")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date clcscfechaSolicitud;

    @Column(name="CLCSC_ESTADO_ID")
    private String clcscEstadoId;

    public Integer getClcscId() {
        return clcscId;
    }

    public void setClcscId(Integer clcscId) {
        this.clcscId = clcscId;
    }

    public Integer getClcscMotivoId() {
        return clcscCdMotivo;
    }

    public void setClcscMotivoId(Integer clcscMotivoId) {
        this.clcscCdMotivo = clcscMotivoId;
    }

    public String getClcscPropuesta() {
        return clcscPropuesta;
    }

    public void setClcscPropuesta(String clcscPropuesta) {
        this.clcscPropuesta = clcscPropuesta;
    }

    public Integer getClcscCdConvenio() {
        return clcscCdConvenio;
    }

    public void setClcscCdConvenio(Integer clcscCdConvenio) {
        this.clcscCdConvenio = clcscCdConvenio;
    }

    public Date getClcscFeCre() {
        return clcscFeCre;
    }

    public void setClcscFeCre(Date clcscFeCre) {
        this.clcscFeCre = clcscFeCre;
    }

    public Date getClcscFeHasta() {
        return clcscFeHasta;
    }

    public void setClcscFeHasta(Date clcscFeHasta) {
        this.clcscFeHasta = clcscFeHasta;
    }

    public String getClcscEstadoId() {
        return clcscEstadoId;
    }

    public void setClcscEstadoId(String clcscEstadoId) {
        this.clcscEstadoId = clcscEstadoId;
    }

    public Date getClcscfechaSolicitud() {
        return clcscfechaSolicitud;
    }

    public void setClcscfechaSolicitud(Date clcscfechaSolicitud) {
        this.clcscfechaSolicitud = clcscfechaSolicitud;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }



    }
```

Y el siguiente controlador:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/generarEndoso", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String generarEndoso(@Valid Endoso endoso, Model model,RedirectAttributes redir,BindingResult result,SessionStatus status) {
        log.info("ingreso a /generarEndoso");
        SolicitudCancelacion solcan = new SolicitudCancelacion();
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
        final String url = System.getProperty("APIMESOS")+"apiEndoso/endoso/cancelacion";
        Date date = new Date();
        endoso.setEjecutivo(1);
        endoso.setMotivoEndoso(Integer.parseInt(endoso.getMotivoId()));
        endoso.setnEndoso(1);
        endoso.setSucursal(1);
        endoso.setUsuario("pmunoz");
        endoso.setnSolicitud(solcan.getClcscId());
        log.info("endoso id: "+endoso.getnSolicitud());
        if(!model.containsAttribute("actualizaFeedback")) {
            model.addAttribute("actualizaFeedback", "0");
        }
        log.info("url: "+url);
        log.info("propuesta: "+endoso.getPropuesta());
        log.info("convenio: "+endoso.getCodConvenio());
        log.info("ejecutivo: "+endoso.getEjecutivo());
        log.info("motivoEndoso: "+endoso.getMotivoEndoso());
        log.info("motivoId: "+endoso.getMotivoId());
        log.info("nEndoso: "+endoso.getnEndoso());
        log.info("sucursal: "+endoso.getSucursal());
        log.info("usuario: "+endoso.getUsuario());
        log.info("fechaSolicitud: "+endoso.getFechaSolicitud());

        solcan.setClcscCdConvenio(endoso.getCodConvenio());
        solcan.setClcscEstadoId("1");
        solcan.setClcscFeCre(date);
        solcan.setClcscMotivoId(endoso.getMotivoEndoso());
        solcan.setClcscPropuesta(endoso.getPropuesta().toString());
        Date date2;
        try {
            date2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(endoso.getFechaSolicitud());
            solcan.setClcscfechaSolicitud(date2);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  

        solcan = solicitudService.save(solcan);
        log.info("solcan id: "+solcan.getClcscId());
```

este es el log que me entrega:

```
2018-11-20 12:19:15 INFO  CancelacionController:generarEndoso 111 - propuesta: 25858
2018-11-20 12:19:15 INFO  CancelacionController:generarEndoso 112 - convenio: 5
2018-11-20 12:19:15 INFO  CancelacionController:generarEndoso 113 - ejecutivo: 1
2018-11-20 12:19:15 INFO  CancelacionController:generarEndoso 114 - motivoEndoso: 701
2018-11-20 12:19:15 INFO  CancelacionController:generarEndoso 115 - motivoId: 701
2018-11-20 12:19:15 INFO  CancelacionController:generarEndoso 116 - nEndoso: 1
2018-11-20 12:19:15 INFO  CancelacionController:generarEndoso 117 - sucursal: 1
2018-11-20 12:19:15 INFO  CancelacionController:generarEndoso 118 - usuario: pmunoz
2018-11-20 12:19:15 INFO  CancelacionController:generarEndoso 119 - fechaSolicitud: 05-11-2018
2018-11-20 12:19:16 INFO  CancelacionController:generarEndoso 135 - solcan id: 9
```

Y esto es lo que insertó en la base:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que cuando obtengo el id, respecto de lo que hay en la base de datos, está 50 números desfasados, no sé si oracle deja en caché cierta cantidad de id o es un error de spring

Comment: [Este post de Stackoverflow en ingles te podria ayudar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7171829/1305745). Basicament se resume al algoritmo que se esta usando para generar las ids secuenciales. Si usas el Hi-lo, es normal tener ese comportamiento.

Comment: @cavpollo puedes considerar hacer eso una respuesta.

Comment: @cavpollo mejoró la situacion, efectuvamente es por el algoritm hi-lo, pero ahora tengo un desface de 1, ya configuré mi entity con allocationSize=1